# How does TeXmaker compile .tex documents so quickly?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker

It seems like in TeXmaker, it takes only about two seconds for me to compile a document, whereas the same document with pdflatex takes four seconds to compile. This difference, of course, is much more evident with larger files.

How does TeXmaker do it in half the time, and is it possible to make pdflatex just as fast?

Comment: Erh, you might want to give more details. TeXMaker is presumably just running pdflatex as well.

Comment: You're right, it is. However, it's definitely faster on Texmaker. I can't see why. I'm using basically the same command as Texmaker is, except for the `-synctex=1` option [edit: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to matter]

Comment: @daleif I don't know what other details to add, honestly. Since I'm using the same command in both I feel like TeXmaker *might* have some behind-the-scene optimizations which help it do this. That's why I'm asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeXmaker, like other IDEs for LaTeX, simply calls the appropriate command line binary (most likely `pdflatex`). What it does do is not show the *output* to the terminal. Writing to the terminal takes a non-zero time, so the difference is likely due to this. (There are some systems which incorporate non-standard TeX binaries, but TeXmaker is not one of them.)

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I ran a command which hid the terminal window while compiling it and it now seems to compile at TeXmaker's speed. Thanks!